# Salesforce Certification

Tags: integration

Does Salesforce certification have any API?

Need to add salesforce certification API in integration. to find the certifications of users by using emailId.

but can't find the salesforce certification API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce provides a public means of [verifying credentials](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/credentials/verification) through Trailhead, but it's not a consumable REST API. You're required to complete a ReCaptcha before you can utilize the tool.

I don't believe there is a public-facing API to obtain credential details. It would be an invitation to spam and other bad actors.